# Match hyphen in combination with new line character

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

```
import re
string = re.sub(r'-\n', '', string)
```

I want to tokenize words of a text. The problem is, that all words, which are at the end of a line, are tokenized wrong. So i have to remove the hyphen before a new line character.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a lookahead to identify the newline, rather than including it in part of the sub operation:

```
string = re.sub(r'-(?=\n)', '', string)
```

### Demo